# Auto delete a cell after 180 days and shift row

Tags: excel, vba

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.  I have looked everywhere and I am unable to figure out the code on how to accomplish my goal.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjHYK.png)

I am looking for a code to auto delete a cell after 180 days and shift the remaining contents of the row over. EX: i have a date in cell D9 once that date highlights blue and is past 180 days from todays date...I would like it to auto delete and shift the remaining row details to the left 2 cells.  So D9 and and E9 would auto delete and would move F9 to D9 and so on for the remainder of the row. Please let me know if that makes sense.  Thank you again for taking the time to review my question.

Answer (score 1):

If by "auto delete" you mean you want it to run every time you open the workbook, you can do this:

1) With workbook open:

2) Hold down your "Alt" key and hit "F11" to open the VBA editor

3) In the Project Explorer on the left, under "Microsoft Excel Objects", double-click "ThisWorkbook".

4) Paste the following code into the editor:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()


    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    If CDate(ws.Range("D9")) < DateAdd("d", -180, Now) Then
        ws.Range("D9, E9").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    End If


End Sub
```

5) Save and close the workbook

You could also add the same code (without the sub and end sub lines) to any existing macro you are running and it would execute with that other macro. If, by "auto delete" you mean you want it to happen without you even having to open the workbook. You could use the "Task Scheduler" in Windows to open the workbook and run the code according to a preset schedule.

If this answers your question, please remember to mark as answered, so everyone will know you have your solution. If this doesn't answer your question, let me know why not and I'll try to help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP wanted to look through column D but this more than meets the stated requirements after E9 was included in the delete.

Comment: @Jeeped I try to take them as literally as possible, so I don't waste a bunch of my time going in an unnecessary direction. I can always revise. Thanks for the upvote, if that was you!